# "Callback function is not a function" Error when following Google Cloud Scheduler / PubSub tutorial

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to create to a start/stop schedule for my VM instance on Google Cloud. I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule)created by Google but when I get to the **(Optional) Verify the functions work** section and try to test the *stopInstancePubSub* function and pass the *{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsICJsYWJlbCI6ImVudj1kZXYifQo="}* JSON object I get the following error:

```
2019-06-09 17:23:54.225 EDT
stopInstancePubSub
ipmdukx38xpw
TypeError: callback is not a function at exports.stopInstancePubSub (/srv/index.js:55:5) at /worker/worker.js:825:24 at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, am I missing another argument to pass to the function?

*Edit: The code being used is taken from Googles Tutorial:

```
const Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer;
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();

/**
 * Stops a Compute Engine instance.
 *
 * Expects a PubSub message with JSON-formatted event data containing the
 * following attributes:
 *  zone - the GCP zone the instances are located in.
 *  instance - the name of a single instance.
 *  label - the label of instances to start.
 *
 * Exactly one of instance or label must be specified.
 *
 * @param {!object} event Cloud Function PubSub message event.
 * @param {!object} callback Cloud Function PubSub callback indicating completion.
 */
exports.stopInstancePubSub = (event, callback) => {
  try {
    const pubsubMessage = event.data;
    const payload = _validatePayload(
      JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString())
    );
    const options = {filter: `labels.${payload.label}`};
    compute.getVMs(options).then(vms => {
      vms[0].forEach(instance => {
        if (payload.zone === instance.zone.id) {
          compute
            .zone(payload.zone)
            .vm(instance.name)
            .stop()
            .then(data => {
              // Operation pending.
              const operation = data[0];
              return operation.promise();
            })
            .then(() => {
              // Operation complete. Instance successfully stopped.
              const message = 'Successfully stopped instance ' + instance.name;
              console.log(message);
              callback(null, message);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              callback(err);
            });
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
  }
};

/**
 * Validates that a request payload contains the expected fields.
 *
 * @param {!object} payload the request payload to validate.
 * @return {!object} the payload object.
 */
function _validatePayload(payload) {
  if (!payload.zone) {
    throw new Error(`Attribute 'zone' missing from payload`);
  } else if (!payload.label) {
    throw new Error(`Attribute 'label' missing from payload`);
  }
  return payload;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code for review.

Comment: Your JSON is fine. You will need to post the code.

Comment: Please see the edit, the code is the same as from the tutorial linked above. @JohnHanley

Comment: In debugging, you have an error message. Now map that error message to the file and line in your question. This will help us figure out the problem. Note: Making assumptions is the root of a lot of bugs. Therefore, when posting a question, we will not assume anything. We need all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `exports.stopInstancePubSub = (event, context, callback) => { ... }`

The [source repo has been updated](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js).

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue just an hour ago :)

Try taking `callback` as 3rd param:

`exports.stopInstancePubSub = (event, data, callback) => { ... }`

Hope it helps

Comment: Does this have to be with a Cloud Storage or PubSub function, or can it be with Firestore? The documentation says "...in response to an event, such as a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic, a change in a Cloud Storage bucket, or a Firebase event." But I'm getting the "callback is not an error" when triggering from a Firestore event. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the runtime version.

Try to use: RuntimeNode.js 6 (Deprecated)

This solution solved for me