# Error: function execution failed. Error when following Google Cloud Scheduler / PubSub tutorial

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was following the tutorial found [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule). However, when I first tested it, I've got the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548965/callback-function-is-not-a-function-error-when-following-google-cloud-schedule) as *“Callback function is not a function” Error when following Google Cloud Scheduler / PubSub tutorial*. The solution suggested did change things. But I still get an error:

> Error: function execution failed. Details:
>
> First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.

I am correctly passing a JSON with data element in it. The base64 encode isn't an issue for I'm getting the exact same error when I copy the event (JSON with data) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I have noticed that:

1. They are using "label" instead of "instance". But the function described in the tutorial uses "instance". Still fails with the same error when corrected, though. The elements inside the JSON aren't a problem. The data check doesn't happen at all.
2. The functions have changed a lot in [the repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js) but never have been updated in the tutorial. Even the [package.json](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/scheduleinstance/package.json) file has changed.

Once everything is replaced with the newest code, it works correctly.

Leaving this here for others, because searching the web for the exact error with the function names doesn't give any result.